# -[__NSArrayI objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance IN xcode6 objective-c ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, viewcontroller

I am trying to learn objective-c, and came across some crash I couldn't resolve.
I believe it's one of the basic problems, but I am new here and got lost in the middle.

I have :

- ModelViewController.h
- ModelViewController.m
- Schedule.h
- Schedule.m

in ModelViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FetchScheduleVC : UIViewController 
    @property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;
@end
```

in ModelViewController.m

```
#import "ModelViewController.h"
#import "Schedule.h"

@implementation Model
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++){
        [_myMutableArray addObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt: i]
    }
}
- (IBAction)saveBtn:(UIButton *)sender {
     Schedule *newSchedule = [[Schedule alloc]init];
    [newSchedule createClassFromArray: _myMutableArray];
}
@end
```

in Schedule.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Schedule : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *classArray;
-(void) createClassFromArray: (NSArray *) selectedArr;
@end
```

in Schedule.m

```
#import "Schedule.h"

@implementation Schedule
-(void) createClassFromArray: (NSArray *) selectedArr {
    for(NSNumber *i in selectedArr){
    NSLog(@"number in array is : %@", i);
    }
}
@end
```

I simplified my codes a little, but the basic flow is the same.
When I run this, and click a button to call - (IBAction)saveBtn:(UIButton *)sender, I get:

```
-[__NSArrayI objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcb61d2fd10
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcb61d2fd10'
```

Anything wrong doings in sending NSArray through Method up here?

Comment: Where do you init _myMutableArray?

Comment: _myMutableArray is not a mutable array. Hence you're getting this crash.

Comment: -1 You've accepted an answer that has nothing to do with your question.  The question is misleading and unhelpful to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only tell you what's happening in your code, not where it's happening, as you've not posted the offending code.

The `objectForKeyedSubscript` method is called for `NSDictionary` subscripting, for example:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"key" : @"value" };
NSString *value = dict[@"key"];    // HERE
```

so it looks like you are doing something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i < 3; i++){
    [_myMutableArray addObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt: i]
}
NSNumber *num = _myMutableArray[@"3"];    // !!!!
```

One more thing I can tell you, it's not to do with uninitialized array as Objective-C simply ignores attempts to dereference `nil` objects and this exception has gone further than that.

Answer (score 0):

As you have declared myMutableArray with copy semantic as-

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;
```

this will sends a copy message to the array, which results in an immutable copy.

So, to use above semantics on `NSMutableArray` you need to override the "setter" method as -

```
- (void)setArray:(NSArray *)newArray 
{
    if ( array != newArray ) 
{ 
        [array release];
        array = [newArray mutableCopy];
    }
}
```

the above setter method just assign the reference of mutable copy of the newArray to the array, which help you to mutate the objects and thus avoiding the error.

Comment: @Joon.P This is not the cause of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

In the codes above, I forgot to include

```
_myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

although i had that in my actual code.

the problem was very dumb. Sorry for this misleading question. Hope you just ignore this question cuz it's due to such a careless mistake.

In my actual code, I had duplicate variable names like this:

in Schedule.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Schedule : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *selectedArr;
-(void) createClassFromArray: (NSArray *) selectedArr;
@end
```

..very.. careless mistake.